# Vpnc password not stored in network manager anymore

Tags: network-manager, password, vpnc

Unfortunately I've ran into a major Ubuntu crisis. One too many these last period.
After recent updates suddenly I'm not able to use my VPN connection anymore. 
It worked perfect for a long time. I need to use a vpnc connection to access internet. However now it's not possible to access the VPN (greyed out) or add a new one in the menu. Only when specifically going trough 'edit connections'. When going there I notice the user password and group password are never saved anymore. Also when specifically selecting to store the password.
Totally weird and very disappointing.
Every help is more then welcome. I'm without internet at my laptop for now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` if exists your VPN config file. Then, check if the parameter `password-flags=1` is there.

Look also this man page about [Network Manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html). Maybe you can find something else that can help.

Cheers,
Vinícius Leite

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot. If someone already faced this problem, let me know.

Comment: This is not proven helpful unfortunately. Should anyone have a guideline how to fix this, please let me know. This bug is very inconvenient!